# How to dismiss keyboard in UISearchController when changing focus in tvos?

Tags: swift, tvos, uisearchcontroller

I'm completely new to tvos and I'm trying to implement a UISearchController view where, in my SearchResultsViewController, I have two UICollectionViews displayed one above the other:
[image]

The problem is that when the user swipes down to select one of the items in the UICollectionView, the keyboard doesn't dismiss. Even swiping back up to select the keyboard doesn't fully scroll up and it's impossible to see what you're typing. The resulting view is this:
[image]

Ideally, I'd like to dismiss the keyboard when the user swipes down to focus on anything else in the interface. I looked at Apple's [tvos UIKit Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/samplecode/UICatalogFortvOS/Introduction/Intro.html) and their example shows a UISearchController which dismisses the keyboard when changing focus, but I don't see that they're doing anything differently.

Here is the code I'm using to setup my UISearchController when the user clicks on a button:

```
@IBAction func onSearchButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let resultsController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(SearchResultsViewController.storyboardID) as? SearchResultsViewController else { fatalError("Unable to instantiate a SearchResultsViewController.") }

    // Create and configure a `UISearchController`.
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    let searchPlaceholderText = NSLocalizedString("Search for a Show or Movie", comment: "")
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = searchPlaceholderText

    // Present the search controller from the root view controller.
    guard let rootViewController = view.window?.rootViewController else { fatalError("Unable to get root view controller.") }
    rootViewController.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After quite a bit of trial and error, I was able to figure out the solution.

The keyboard will automatically dismiss itself as long as:
1) The item the user focuses on is inside of a scrollview
2) The scrollview content size is larger than the screen height by at least 1px (1081px).

Comment: I'm struggling with this issue, changing the content height of the scrollview didn't fix it for me. How did you structure your view controllers?

Comment: @AaronStephenson I am also facing same issue. Did you find any solution for the problem?

Answer (score 3):

After quite a lot of trial and error, finally I figured out.
The reason is that you have **nested ScrollViews** in searchResultsController.

"ScrollViews" of-course includes UICollectionView, UITableView, and UIScrollView.

According to my investigation, UISearchController behaves as follows.

1. If the first view which gets focused in searchResultsController is subview of the inner scrollView (which is the horizontal UICollectionView, in your case), then **you won't get keyboard hidden** as expected.
2. Interestingly, if the first view which gets focused in searchResultsController is subview of outer scrollView, then you will get keyboard hidden completely, animated, just as expected (!).

I think this is sort of UIKit's bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same layout and wasn't able to achieve this so far. I believe you return false in tableView(tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool so that each cells in collection view can scroll horizontally with proper focus behavior. I think it's actually causing the issues. If you make the first cell in the tableview focusable the problem goes away but of course focus behavior is not desired. I just found that out today and will try more tomorrow to find out what I can do about this. I sense that I will need a new design that allows me to use a single collectionview or tableview that has its cells focusable in resultsController. Hope this is easily achievable in tvOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

Work Around Solution: Add one dummy cell at indexPath.row == 0 with height as 1 pixel and enable the focus on it.